# Why The Image Segmantation Process applied on Grayscale Images?

Tags: image, image-segmentation

i am working on my final project in master i want to understand a few things;
please someone tell me why most of image segmentation process applied on grayscale images?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of image segmentation methods that use color. The primary problem with Color images, or other multidimensional images, like Remote sensing Hyperspectral images, is that they don't have a natural ordering defined on their vector valued pixels. This leads to problems of locating a [good color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) before one can perform intensity based segmentation. This usually entails a usually nonlinear [Dimensionality reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction). One can find [surveys](http://iristown.engr.utk.edu/~koschan/paper/coseg.pdf) on Color image segmentation algorithms here which describe these problems more clearly.

Comment: The Color Image Segmentation Survey looks interesting but if that is an answer then can you expand on how up to date the paper is since its date is 1994.

Comment: The question by itself refers to an well known classical problem with color, i thought this reference had good intuitions presented w.r.t to color image segmentation, even though it might be old.

Comment: Good answer, I'd just like to know (selfishly without any research effort) the current state of this problem. Just a suggestion, request. Thanks.

Comment: i work on image segmentation science two years, and i work on MoEA to solve this problem, i asked this question cause i feel that we loss some information falls under the color mode, when we use the grayscale  mode.

Comment: @Jason in this case i suggest google :) - Image segmentation surveys are plenty out there. It really depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer What is MoEA ? And ofcourse Color carries a lot of information and is an important feature.

Comment: MoEA: Multi-objective Evolutionary Algorithms such as:
Genetic Algorithms(GA), particle Swarm Optimization(PSO) ...

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer I have been selectively choosing from RGB values to maximize the slopes in a grayscale image fed into Edge detection algorithms to get around that... to some extent.

Comment: @Jason in your opinion witch one the better? grayscale or RGB!

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer It always depends from my point of view. I transform RGB to {Intensity, Hue, Chroma} then use Hues only when Chroma is large enough, but I have been segmenting images on color alone until recently to get a better result. Though the results have not been too bad. Just a hobby at this point though :)